# Как правильно? Расположилось или Расположилась?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Очень повезло, что Япония, как островное государство, расположилОсь.."

Я всегда забываю к чему идет глагол в таком предложении. Здесь не могу понять Япония расположилась или островное государство расположилось. Помогите, кто разбирается хорошо в русском)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *расположилась*. Вставная конструкция не влияет на род глагола.

Примеры:

- Словно тяжелые оковы спали с нее, и *она*, как человек, вырвавшийся
  из тьмы на свет, светлым и радостным взглядом *оглянулась* кругом
  (Тютчев, курсив мой — N.).
- ...*он*, как дитя малое, *хотел* порадовать нас тем, что грело и
  радовало его самого (В. Астафьев, курсив мой — N.).